# Find the integral $\int \frac{1+x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral can be represented as 
$$
\int \frac{1+x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathrm dx=
\int \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{1/2}\mathrm dx
$$

Substitution $$t=\frac{1+x}{1-x}\Rightarrow x=\frac{t-1}{t+1}\Rightarrow dx=\frac{2}{(t+1)^2}dt\Rightarrow \int\limits \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^{1/2}\mathrm dx=2\int\limits \frac{\sqrt{t}}{(t+1)^2}\mathrm dt$$

What substitution to use for solving the integral $\int\limits \frac{\sqrt{t}}{(t+1)^2}\mathrm dt$?

Comment: Why not using $x=\cos t$ instead?

Answer (score 6):

No substitutions:
$$
\int\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)\,dx
=\arcsin x-\sqrt{1-x^2}+c
$$

You can also do that way; continue with $u=\sqrt{t}$, so $t=u^2$ and $dt=2u\,du$; so you get
$$
\int\frac{4u^2}{(u^2+1)^2}\,du=
\int 2u\cdot\frac{2u}{(u^2+1)^2}\,du
$$
Noticing that $2u$ is the derivative of $u^2+1$ you can use integration by parts
$$
=2u\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{u^2+1}\right)-
\int2\left(-\frac{1}{u^2+1}\right)\,du
=2\arctan u-\frac{2u}{u^2+1}
$$
Do the back substitutions.

Alternative method: set $x=\cos4t$, so you have
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos4t}{1-\cos4t}}=\frac{\cos2t}{\sin2t}
$$
and the integral becomes
$$
-8\int\cos^22t\,dt=-4\int(1+\cos t)\,dt
$$

Comment: "No substitutions": did you just guess that $\int \frac{-x}{1-x^2} dx = \sqrt{1-x^2}$, or did you do the substitution (even just in your head) $y = 1-x^2$...?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The derivative of $1-x^2$ is $-2x$.

Comment: Really?! Thanks for the information! ... More seriously, I think most students will just slap a $\pm 2^k$ coefficient (for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$) and not bother taking the derivative to verify their solution. I'm not sure that "no substitutions" is good advice.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Decomposing the fraction should always a first attempt before undertaking substitutions; the presence of $x^2$ and $x\,dx$ should make a bell ring.

Comment: Of course it should make a bell ring, but there's a big step between being able to guess the solution without making a mistake and having to do a substitution to find the correct solution. Anyway, I don't care enough about this to continue this discussion.

Comment: BTW, the integral in the title (that you answered) and the one in the body of the question were different. It seems that someone edited the title to match the question.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It was a bad edit, in my opinion; judging from the question (*it can be represented as*) the given integral was that of the title and the body of the question only had the alternative representation.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the substitution $u=\sqrt{1-x}$, then $\mathrm{d}u=-\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2\sqrt{1-x}}$ and $\sqrt{1+x}=\sqrt{2-u^2}$. We will also use $u=\sqrt2\sin(\theta)$
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-2\int\sqrt{2-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-2\int\sqrt2\cos(\theta)\cdot\sqrt2\cos(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=-2\int(1+\cos(2\theta))\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\[3pt]
&=-2\theta-\sin(2\theta)+C\\[3pt]
&=-2\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{2}}\right)-\sqrt{1-x^2}+C\\
&=-\arccos(x)-\sqrt{1-x^2}+C\\[6pt]
&=\arcsin(x)-\sqrt{1-x^2}+\left(C-\tfrac\pi2\right)
\end{align}
$$

---

**Explanation of $\boldsymbol{2\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{2}}\right)=\arccos(x)}$**

Let $\alpha=\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}2}\right)$, then $x=1-2\sin^2(\alpha)=\cos(2\alpha)$. Thus, $\alpha=\frac12\arccos(x)$. Therefore,
$$
2\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}2}\right)=\arccos(x)
$$

Comment: I now see that I answered Takahiro Waki's modification of the question, which was subsequently rolled back to the original question. The answer is still correct, but now I see why egreg's answer took the path it did.